# Angular 12 TS1086 (TS) An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context

Tags: angular, typescript

I've been trying to upgrade a Angular 8 project to Angular 12 for a week using the update instructions. Couldn't get past errors so I created Angular 12 project from scratch and added code files. Now in Angular 12, I'm getting 90+ of these errors (plus there are some others as well)

```
TS1086  (TS) An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
c:\myprojects\....\Client\tsconfig.json

c:\myprojects\....\Client\node_modules\
@angular\animations\browser\browser.d.ts
@angular\common\common.d.ts
@angular\compiler\src\ast_path.d.ts
@angular\compiler\src\expression_parser\parser.d.ts 
@angular\compiler\src\render3\view\i18n\context.d.ts
@angular\compiler\src\output\abstract_emitter.d.ts  
@angular\compiler\src\template_parser\binding_parser.d.ts
@angular\core\src\r3_symbols.d.ts
@angular\core\testing\testing.d.ts
@angular\router\testing\testing.d.ts
@angular\platform-browser\animations\animations.d.ts
@angular\router\router.d.ts
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "Myportal",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~12.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-common": "^2.0.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^3.0.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-layout": "^6.3.6",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-menu": "^2.0.5",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-notification": "^2.1.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^4.0.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-progressbar": "^2.0.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-scrollview": "^3.0.4",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-tooltip": "^3.0.3",
    "@progress/kendo-licensing": "^1.2.1",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^4.43.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.13",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.1",
    "flag-icon-css": "^3.5.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.1.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.7.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "typescript": "~4.2.3"
  }
}
```

And tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
  //  "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

I am assuming these are due to some version conflicts, but can't figure out. Please guide

Answer (score 0):

After lot of struggle found out simple solution. I am using Angular with Visual Studio. These errors were actually coming from visual Studio build. After I updated Typescript in Visual Studio to match with what is there in package.json, all typescript errors were gone.